# the reason of using size config in flutter design

Tags: flutter

I am trying to learn the design in filters, but during my research in the existing templets, I found one of them that completely depends on giving any height or width on this file

```js
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

class SizeConfig {
  static late MediaQueryData _mediaQueryData;
  static late double screenWidth;
  static late double screenHeight;
  static double? defaultSize;
  static Orientation? orientation;

  void init(BuildContext context) {
    _mediaQueryData = MediaQuery.of(context);
    screenWidth = _mediaQueryData.size.width;
    screenHeight = _mediaQueryData.size.height;
    orientation = _mediaQueryData.orientation;
  }
}

double getProportionateScreenHeight(double inputHeight) {
  double screenHeight = SizeConfig.screenHeight;
  return (inputHeight / 812.0) * screenHeight;
}


double getProportionateScreenWidth(double inputWidth) {
  double screenWidth = SizeConfig.screenWidth;
  return (inputWidth / 375.0) * screenWidth;
}
```

example :

```js
EdgeInsets.symmetric(
                horizontal: getProportionateScreenWidth(20)),
```

**so what is the difference between that method and giving fixed numbers**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The difference is :

- ##### Method is Device Screen Dependent

  - Produces different heights based on the screen size.
- ##### Fixed numbers is Device Screen Independent

  - Produces same height accross devices of different sizes.

---

Explanation:

Lets assume 2 screens of

1. First Screen `1000px` height ,
2. Second Screen `1500px` height,

*Container of **`100px`** to be produced in these devices*

###### In Method:

Height is calculated as `(inputHeight / 812.0) * screenHeight;`

- First Screen  : Container height `(100/812) * 1000` =  `123.1527 px`
- Second Screen : Container height `(100/812) * 1500` = `184.729 px`

###### In Fixed Value:

Height is `100px` in both First Screen and Second Screen